# WordPress website loading image which is not present in my website

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

My WordPress website takes a lot of time to load pages, a problem that many of us face. I used GT metrix to check my WordPress page and then checked my website waterfall.
One thing I saw taking more than half time of my page is an image which is not uploaded in my website.

check this image of gt metrix waterfall:
[image: check this image of gt metrix waterfall]

I checked it, and I found this is an image which I have not used in my entire webpage. Also I could not find where is this image used.
Same thing happens in different pages that has different images to it.

I deleted one image from my media but now when I check the GT metrix waterfall I get a 404 error code which means its still trying to load that image and I cannot find it.

This is a theme which I had purchased and its not a popular theme like *divi* or *ocean* and hence could not contact the support.

1. How to check where a particular image is used in my webpage using
   the media library (can I do that?)
2. How to find out and remove this image? Or at least is there a way where I can delete the image from the library and hence my webpage should not look for this image wasting its time instead of getting a 404 code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite common indeed, for your specific case i can suggest by starting to search the image name in both code + DB, it MUST be somewhere.

If you cannot find it inside your stuff there's only one answer left: there's some JS third party script that is loading that for you, but in this case i seriously dubt it would be in the same domain as your site.

Using the media library there's not much you can understand, if you are VERY lucky it will have a message like "attached to" but that thing cover like 10% of the cases, most of the time the image ARE used but are not attached to anything like a post, so the media library won't tell you anything

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before a few times, too. Isn't it frustrating!? If you could provide a URL, I (and others, I'm sure) would be happy to take a look and try to figure out what's going on. :)